# How can I allow my dynamic website to be crawled by Adsense, or are there better alternatives?

Tags: adsense

The problem is that AdSense has to crawl your pages to make suitable ads.  If I have dynamic content or user-generated content, then AdSense is not suitable.  How can I modify my site so that it is accessible to the Adsense crawlers, or should I approach the problem of monetizing my site from another angle?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this, but it really is not programming related.

Comment: I would't say its entirely unrelated.  His reasoning for not being able to use Adsense IS programming related.  If he had worded the exact problem differently "How do I allow my dynamic website to be crawled" it would still be open.  Had I the power, I would re-open this question.

Comment: @Neil N: If you can reword this to where I agree, I will edit it and vote for reopen. How's that?

Comment: Sure, with that edit I would even vote to reopen.

Comment: @fskreality: This is a website for programming questions, not web administration and ad revenue.

Answer (score 1):

does your content require a login?

If not then theres no reason Google can't crawl it.  Just because its dynamic or user generated doesnt mean google can't see it.

If it doesn't require a login and Google still cant crawl your site, then you have done something wrong and your site is not SEO'd very well in the first place.

As far as other ad networks go, heres a few off the top of my head

- Burst Media
- ValueClick Media
- Casale Media.

Though keep in mind these are usually much harder to join then Adsense.